# Can I reuse an INPUT parameter within the stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, webforms, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 within asp.net webforms application, built in VS2012 Express for Web...

In my stored procedure, I have an input parameter `@UID_LOGIN AS INT`. This value may be ZERO at the time of the call.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateFromDetailsView]
    @UID_CONTACT   INT,
    @UID_LOGIN     INT,
    @UID_USER_TYPE INT,  -- etc...not shown here...
```

When this value is ZERO, a new LOGIN record is created and the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is used to fetch the new `UID_LOGIN` value as follows:

```
-- Retain the key to the inserted-row.
SET @UID_LOGIN = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Can I be assured from your answer that this new value of `@UID_LOGIN` remains local to the stored procedure and does NOT change the value of the parameter.

Thanks in advance... John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `@UID_LOGIN` will remain `= SCOPE_IDENTITY()` within the `BATCH` until you set it to something else. Each time the procedure is executed you will have to pass in a new `@UID_LOGIN` because you have not given it a default value in your declaration. i.e. `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateFromDetailsView] (@UID_LOGIN = NULL) AS...`

You can test snippets like this.

```
-- Comment out the create procedure part
--CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateFromDetailsView]
--( @UID_CONTACT               INT,
--  @UID_LOGIN                 INT,
--  @UID_USER_TYPE             INT
--)

--declare your variables
declare @UID_CONTACT INT, @UID_LOGIN INT, @UID_USER_TYPE INT

--set your variable
SET @UID_LOGIN = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--do some stuff
INSERT INTO TableA (LOGIN) VALUES @UID_LOGIN

--check variable
SELECT @UID_LOGIN
```

Comment: : Thank you very much -- excellent description for the answer :-) thx...John